# org spreadsheet and collapsing columns

Tags: org-mode, org-table, column

I have a long spreadsheet 30 rows and 60 columns . It is difficult to work on columns as I can not freeze the columns. Is it possible to collapse the columns ?

Comment: Please post a simple example of the kind of work you would like to do. For example, did you want to view only certain columns for reading? Do you need to change the cell data in the table? Thanks!

Comment: I need to change data

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether the following will help in your case, but I hope it will be of some use (and it may be useful to others).

You can control the width of a column with `cookies`. The [Tables/Column width and alignment](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment) section of the manual describes this as follows (and contains additional useful information):

> ```
> Sometimes a single field or a few fields need to carry more text,
> leading to inconveniently wide columns.  Maybe you want to hide away
> several columns or display them with a fixed width, regardless of
> content, as shown in the following example.
>
>     |---+---------------------+--------|           |---+-------...|...|
>     |   | <6>                 |        |           |   | <6>   ...|...|
>     | 1 | one                 | some   |   ----\   | 1 | one   ...|...|
>     | 2 | two                 | boring |   ----/   | 2 | two   ...|...|
>     | 3 | This is a long text | column |           | 3 | This i...|...|
>     |---+---------------------+--------|           |---+-------...|...|
>
> To set the width of a column, one field anywhere in the column may
> contain just the string `<N>` where ‘N’ specifies the width as a number
> of characters.
> ```

Also, there is a new dynamic column shrinking feature in recent upstream org-mode. It is described thus in the [ORG-NEWS](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/09cf4a075efe62262cb103605c5bd9c6f5cdcae2/etc/ORG-NEWS#L1658) file:

> ```
> *** Dynamically narrow table columns
>     
> With `C-c TAB`, it is now possible to narrow a column to the width
> specified by a width cookie in the column, or to 1 character if there
> is no such cookie.  The same keybinding expands a narrowed column to
> its previous state.
>
> Editing the column automatically expands the whole column to its full
> size.
> ```

Comment: To install the latest org-mode distro from packages and use it instead of the built-in version, the following comment helped me: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/319#issuecomment-471274348.